# Problem sending images POST

Tags: iphone, objective-c, post, uiimage

For several days, I look for what's wrong in my code but without success, and now I really want to know what's wrong.
The problem is that I want to send an UIImage from my Iphone to my server, but I receive a blank image on my server everytime... I'm not sure, but I think the problem come from the image that I convert. The UIImage come from the method takePicture.
Please check my code :

First I call takePicture and :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)aPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
self.testImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

testImage is a property of my ViewController.
Then I make this to send the UIImage :

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(testImage)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver/mytest.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"tmp.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"userfile"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

and to see the result :

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"response: %@", responseString);

// Use when fetching binary data
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Request Failed Error: %@", error);
}
```

and then I receive a blank image on my server...
Please help me ='(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from the high resolution image. My connection was too slow. When I'm using wifi the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually sending a URL encoded POST body, as opposed to a multi-part POST body, which is required to send data like you want. So you just need to do the following before you start the request:

```
request.postFormat = ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate,

look at your code here:
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(testImage)];

you can change the picture quality by adding a number in the bracket for the dpi you would like it to be, for example, if i wanted it to be in 90 dpi quality i would have written it like this: [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(testImage,90)]

i noticed now that your picture is in .PNG format , i always worked with .JPEG and it worked 
so i think you should give it a try...

good luck